# strace is returning a lot of open("/etc/hosts", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) for a php file

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, strace

I'm trying to debug why a PHP of mine is using so much of the CPU.

After running strace like this:

```
strace -e open,close php /scripName.php
```

It shows me all of the files that it uses and when I think it reaches the part of the code where it uses a MySql connection, it returns this:

```
open("/etc/host.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
close(3)                                = 0
open("/etc/resolv.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
close(3)                                = 0
open("/etc/hosts", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)  = 3
close(3)                                = 0
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_dns.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
close(3)                                = 0
open("/etc/resolv.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
close(3)                                = 0
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 4
close(4)                                = 0
close(3)                                = 0
open("/etc/hosts", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)  = 3
close(3)                                = 0
close(3)                                = 0
close(3)                                = 0
open("/etc/hosts", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)  = 3
close(3)                                = 0
close(3)                                = 0
close(3)                                = 0
open("/etc/hosts", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)  = 3
close(3)                                = 0
close(3)                                = 0
close(3)                                = 0
open("/etc/hosts", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)  = 3
close(3)                                = 0
close(3)                                = 0
close(3)                                = 0
```

and a **LOT** more of those

```
open("/etc/hosts", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)  = 3
close(3)                                = 0
close(3)                                = 0
close(3)                                = 0
```

each one taking quite a bit of time actually.

I tried pinpointing the problem by commenting lines until this didn't happen anymore, and I reached this class:

```
<?php
include_once 'config.php';

class db extends PDO {      
    public $dbtipo = DBTIPO;
    public $host = DBHOST;
    public $user = DBUSER;
    public $pass= DBPASS;
    public $db = DBNAME;

    function __construct(){
        $dns = $this->dbtipo.':host='.$this->host.";dbname=".$this->db;
        parent::__construct( $dns, $this->user, $this->pass ,
            array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
    }
}
?>
```

if I comment this line:

```
parent::__construct( $dns, $this->user, $this->pass ,
            array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
```

Then this doesn't happen anymore.

FYI, this class is used in another one like this:

```
public function getDataFromDb(){
    $connection = new db();
    $query = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM table");
    $query->execute();
    return $query;
}
```

The constants are defined in the config.php file as this:

```
define('DBTIPO', 'mysql');
define('DBHOST', 'mysite.com');
define('DBUSER', 'user');
define('DBPASS', 'password');
define('DBNAME', 'database_name');
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The host needs to resolve `mysite.com` to an IP address, so it looks in `/etc/hosts` where it presumably doesn't find it and then checks `/etc/resolv.conf` for the name servers to use for resolution and then presumably issues a DNS query to one of those name servers.

Depends on the desired operation, but if the MySQL server is on the same host then use `localhost`.  If not then maybe add it to the `hosts` file.

Not sure how this relates to the CPU utilization, but answers the `hosts` and `resolv.conf` question.

Comment: You're right. It looks like this doesn't relate to the CPU, but it did answer my question. Thanks. (I can't accept it for 3 more minutes)